# Firebase Cloud Messaging token is not generating

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM setup in AndroidStudio- tools- Firebase Assistant in Cloud Messaging setup to Successfully. So, setup is Corrected but Token is not generated.token is not generated in logcat and Config Class through token display in MainActivity but its display null. Uninstalled app after the run issue continues. I also try different emulator but not any solution.

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String newToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + newToken);
        Config.TOKEN = newToken;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

build.gradle(Project-level)

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

build.gradle(app-level)

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: uninstall the app and try again...

Comment: do you have googleservies.json file under your app directory?

Comment: yes,googleservies.json file  in app directory

Answer (score 3):

At any point in your app, you can use this code to get the Firebase instance ID token if you need it:

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Your FirebaseInstanceIdService will only get executed when the token changes.  [The Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) states:

> Instance ID is stable except when:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data

If none of those things happen to your app, then your FirebaseInstanceIdService will only ever get executed the first time that your app runs when it is installed on a device.

Answer (score 1):

For firebase version greater then 18.0.0  `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` is deprecated.

Now we have to use below method for getting token programmatically.

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                        return@addOnCompleteListener
                    }
                    
                    val token = it.result
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMsgService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

add this to manifest

Answer (score 0):

Add      `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>` in your manifest firebase service.

```
<service
                android:name=".common.firebase.FirebaseMessagingService"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```